# Where to put cache initializers in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, activerecord

I'm trying to optimize my application and load certain things into the Rails cache (eventually memcached) at application start. Essentially I have a few tables in my database that only exist for normalization purposes and RARELY change. When they change, I can handle the logic to update the cache.

Where should I write the 'initializer' to read these various models and load them into the cache? I tried writing a traditional initializer, but it gets run BEFORE my models actually exist... I essentially need to load all my models and stuff, then create the cache, then run the application. How can I enter that middle state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either put this code in a file in your lib directory and require the model files first, or directly into your model files so that the initialization runs after your model is defined:

```
class NormalizedTable
  ...
end

CacheInitializer.fill_cache_with :normalized_table
```

Where CacheInitializer#fill_cache_with is defined in your initializers or lib directory. I would also recommend that you run these functions in the background, for example in a delayed job. If you are running this code every time you load up your Rails app it will slow your boot process down and it's probably not necessary that the data is in your cache at all times - i.e you app can use the database while the cache is being populated.

Comment: I see your point about using delayed_job (we are already using it for other stuff), but there are literally like 5 records and it's hardly worth using delayed_job for at this point. I'm a little confused though... If I initialize in the model, won't it write the the cache EVERY time I call Model.foo or @model.foo?

Comment: Not in production. In development it will. I'm assuming you'll have some kind of check for this. If you want to use cache in development then you should put this code in an autoload_once_paths directory and make sure you include your model first.

Comment: You can check dev/production like this: CacheInitializer.fill if Rails.env == 'production'

Comment: I'm going to upvote, but I'm going to wait a few hours at least until I mark as correct because this seems like a somewhat hacky solution. Maybe someone else will have a better implementation

Comment: Sounds good. Keep in mind that you can always simply wait for the first DB call to the information, after which the data will go into your cache and you'll no longer have DB calls. Since it's only a single cal it might be worth simply letting your application take care of this instead of trying to pre-populate the cache.

Comment: Wait... I'm confused.. You're saying that the first time I rails runs "SELECT * FROM table..." that it's automatically cached? Right now I'm trying to write things from the table into Rails.cache and read them. In console (on dev), it always runs the query...

Comment: No, you have to surround you call with a Rails.cache.fetch statement. It won't automatically cache. For example: Rail.cache.fetch('normalized_table'){ NormalizedTable.all }. This will default to the database if the cache is not present, but also populate the cache.

Comment: How do I get a specific record then?

Comment: Up to you, but you might do something like this: Rails.cache.fetch("normalized_table/#{id}"){ NormalizedTable.find(id) }